# I want to have an alternate implementation of isEqualNode() of org.w3c.dom.Node API

Tags: java, xml, dom, recursion

I want to have a implementation of isEqualNode() of the org.w3c.dom.Node Java API which ignores the values of the attributes in the Nodes getting compared. Any help?

Comment: Extend the class and override the method?

Comment: I am not able to figure out how to write the logic, it would be helpful if anyone helps there, also i cannot just implement the interface Node it has too many methods, i just want to change the behavior of this particular method.

Comment: You have two options: Either you manually edit the `.jar` file that you imported (or you copy/paste it and change your bit), or you `Override` it. You can override the class, and just do super(parameters) for all methods except the one you want to change.